# How to deal with DeadObjectException on killed Service?

Tags: java, android, exception

I am getting `DeadObjectException` in my code. Below, I describe my setup, and what I have tried to fix the issue.

---

A `Service` **S** is started from `Application` **A**.

`Activity` **B** (from another application) communicates with that service using `Messenger` and `IBinder` interfaces. This activity is also started from the same service. On a button press inside this activity, I am supposed to send a message back to the service. I frequently get `DeadObjectException` on button press.

I understand that the most likely cause for this is - system killed and restarted the service, and the activity has old reference to it. Beyond this, I haven't found much information online.

This is what I have tried:

- I used a `startForeground()` in service, and I could see that the service was running (notification in notification area) continuously. I still got the exception.
- On a system reboot, I do not get this exception for a while.
- The exception is intermittent. I do not have a 100% repro. However, in the following scenario, I always get the exception:

  1. Start app A (thi also start the service S).
  2. Start activity B, everything works fine.
  3. Restart the service by redeploying app A.
  4. Navigate to activity B. **The exception happens**.
  5. At this point, if I restart activity B, the exception disappears.
- This led me to conclude that if I made sure that the activity B is fresh every time the service starts, this exception would disappear. I then tried to deliver a murdering intent to activity B, prior to starting it. (Activity has a `BroadcastReceiver`, and calls `finish()` in `onReceive()`). The problem is, if the activity pauses, `Intent`s are not delivered to it. Also, I see `onDestroy()` being hit in a nutshell, because Android manages activity life cycle, intents are not guaranteed to be delivered to it. I also tried extending a `BaseActivity` as mentioned in [this stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154743/android-clearing-the-full-activity-stack)
- I also tried setting `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` (in addition to usual `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`), with no better results.

Now, I feel as if I am out of options. Has anyone faced similar problems? Is there something I can try? Is it possible to catch the exception and then rebind the service?

Answer (score 3):

In Activity B, implement an `IBinder.DeathRecipient` interface (possibly wrapped in a custom class) and register it with the `IBinder` from your service via `IBinder.linkToDeath()`.  Your callback will be hit when/if the `Service` dies for some reason and Activity B can gracefully cleanup any internal book keeping it has as well as re-bind to the service.