# Clear back stack : android api 11

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, android-4.2-jelly-bean

AS the question points out, i want to clear the back stack. I have gone through most of the links for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947916/android-remove-all-the-previous-activities-from-the-back-stack) and also found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794506/android-clear-the-back-stack?answertab=votes#tab-top) with a marked answer which could be flagged against this question

But, before it is marked as a duplicate, there are specific things happening in the app.

I have used the same code in the answer provided in the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794506/android-clear-the-back-stack?answertab=votes#tab-top) but since this does not work in api levels below 11, i used a code that would finish the activity if at all the activity is the next one in the stack.

I cannot use the singleTop keyword in the manifest as i need to maintain the activity, such that the user can get to the activity on pressing the back button

The **CLEAR_TASK** and also **CLEAR_TOP** and **NEW_TASK** flags work well with Honeycomb version and ice cream sandwich versions,

But, the same and also the patched code to finish an activity does not work on api level 11(**JELLY_BEAN_MR1**), it however works on **JELLY_BEAN** and also **JELLY_BEAN_MR2** version codes.

Could anyone please guide me as to what i should do to clear the stack history?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154743/android-clearing-the-full-activity-stack

Comment: @Segi m sure the patch m using to kill the activities almost works the same as the broadcast receiver, but then calling finish just creates a white screen but it really does not exit the application altogether

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille how u resolved ?